# Poor Video Performance In Chrome

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, google-chrome, video

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and Chrome, but I'm noticing that video performance feels a quite a bit slower than when my PC could do in Windows.  Is there something I'm missing that would improve things?

My PC is reasonably powerful

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz
- ASUS STRIX GeForce GTX 970
- 32GB RAM on a fast SSD

I think I'm using the correct driver from nvidia

> filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
>   alias:          char-major-195-* version:        390.77 supported:
>   external license:        NVIDIA srcversion:
>   209B1D0CB123DE466F700AD alias:
>   pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00* alias:
>   pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00* alias:
>   pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00* depends:        ipmi_msghandler
>   retpoline:      Y name:           nvidia vermagic:
>   4.15.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload  signat:         PKCS#7

I don't know if it helps at all, but inside Chrome if I go to **chrome://gpu/** I can see the following

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Unavailable
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Skia Deferred Display List: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Disabled
Surface Control: Disabled
Surface Synchronization: Enabled
Video Decode: Unavailable
Viz Service Display Compositor: Enabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
```

I can see that is says 'Video Decode: Unavailable' - does that mean anything?